# Is there a way to get scheme url of an installed app? (Android)

Tags: android, url-scheme, mobile-chrome

From the mobile web, I am trying to open an application that I installed from the store.

So far, I found out that apps can be opened by scheme URLs and deep links,
but couldn't find out a way to get the scheme URL of the app implemented by others.

The best I can do for now is open the google play store link.
Is there a way to open the app directly?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like I didn't need the scheme URL after all.

I just needed to go to the google play store site and get the app id,

Then

```
location.href = market://launch?id={APP_ID};
```